# What is 'a valid next URL' on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I keep getting this error: "Requires valid next URL" while trying to redirect to that adress: http://www.facebook.com/authorize.php?api_key=API_CODE_HERE&v=1.0&ext_perm=read_stream&next=http://apps.facebook.com/my-app-name/

I have also tried replacing 'http://apps.facebook.com/my-app-name/' with 'http://my-app.com' but hasn't helped either.

So what shall I put in 'next' in that adress?

Comment: No, it hasn't helped. I think it is automatically urlencoded when I use fb:redirect

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fixed it myself. Just used login.php instead of authorize.php and 'req_perms' instead 'ext_perms'